# Is it possible to specify the TCP port in mappings in the axis NSToPkg.properties file?

Tags: java, axis, wsdl2java

I'm using the Axis 1.4 axis-wsdl2java ant task to create stub code for a web service hosted on port 8080 of a webserver. I've used the NStoPkg.properties file successfully in the past to map the webserver namespace to a convenient java package name with config lines like this:

```
http\://webserver/somedir/service=com.blah.blah
```

But when I try to do the same thing for the service hosted on port 8080 like this:

```
http\://webserver\:8080/somedir/service=com.blah.blah
```

the wsdl2java tool doesn't seem to recognize the mapping. I've tried as many variations as I can think of, all to no avail. Is this not possible, or am I doing something wrong?

[Edit: I forgot to mention that when using the command-line WSDL2Java utility's -N option, there is no problem and the packages are remapped successfully. It's just the options file-based version of this that I can't get to work.]

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure namespace in wsdl file matches
2. You can see log "[axis-wsdl2java] INFO: Loaded namespace-to-package mapping file "NStoPkg.propertis" if the AXIS ant task read the NStoPkg.propertis file.

It works as i tried http\://host\:port/url, but http://host:port/url does not work.

Answer (score 0):

strange that doesn't work. Can't recall why you might need the escape character. Did you try enclosing in quotes?

Comment: Tried a few combinations with quotes, but no luck :-( But thanks anyway!

Comment: with no current project set up with those tools I have nothing easily handy to test with so I'm fresh out of ideas. Sorry, good luck.